# Input default CSS

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/fj5u5Lk3/

```
<input type="text"></input>
```

On focus, this field gets a blue border, by default. Where can I find the default value and color code of it? I want to add my own, but it gets overwritten. I want to remove it, but then want to add it back on, and can't without knowing the default values.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `input[type="text"]:focus`:

```css
input[type="text"]:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #61C5FA;
    border:1px solid #5AB0DB;
}
input[type="text"]:focus:hover {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #61C5FA;
    border:1px solid #5AB0DB;
    border-radius:0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"></input>
```

Comment: But where from do I get the default value? I want to add my own style, but in certain situations I want to revert it back to default(the blue outline). Where can I find that exact default property?

Comment: What do you mean default? Each browser use different style.

Comment: Hm, you're right. Didn't know that. Guess I'm asking for Chrome's default outline, then.

Comment: Hmm for chrome i think this will work `input {
    outline: 2px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
}`

Comment: Strange how you can make a color with no color code.

Answer (score 1):

It's called outline property. You can set

```
outline: 0px;
```

to disable it. And, for example

```
p {
    outline-style: dotted;
    outline-color: #00ff00;
}
```

for some properties. You can read something here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline-color.asp or just search "outline css property"

Answer (score 0):

from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_form.asp) :

### Focused Inputs

By default, some browsers will add a blue outline around the input when it gets focus (clicked on). You can remove this behavior by adding `outline: none;` to the input.